# Testing for a null model attribute in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, mockito

I have been using Mockito to test my Spring controller methods but am confused with the behaviour of the following failing test:

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getPage", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getPage(Model model) {

    String myString = myService.someMethod();

    model.addAttribute("myString", myString);
    return "myTemplate";
}
```

Test:

```
@Test public void testGetPage() throws Exception {

    String myString = null;

    when(mockService.someMethod()).thenReturn(myString);

    mockMvc.perform(get("/getPage"))
        .andExpect(status().isOk())
        .andExpect(model().size(1)) // this passes
        .andExpect(model().attribute("myString", myString))   // fails: "Model attribute 'myString' does not exist 
        .andExpect(model().attributeExists("myString"))    // fails: "Model attribute 'myString' does not exist 
        ;
 }
```

So what is the test detecting when it returns model().size(1) if not the myString variable? Is there a way I can list all the attributes associated with the model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The model is a map with a key of *myString* and value of null. To make the model size zero, don't add any attributes to it.

You could have 1000 attributes, all initialized to null. Size would be 1000.